# setTimeout not working in try/catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, ionic-framework

I am waiting for a provider to update `this.myprovider.SomeVarIsNotUndefined`. I cannot use a Promise to make my script wait so I have come up with this, but it only seems to run once. So `setTimeout()` is not re-firing in the `catch` area when `this.myprovider.SomeVarIsNotUndefined` = `undefined` even though  `console.log(err)` is triggering.

```
someFunction(){

  try {

      if(this.myprovider.SomeVarIsNotUndefined){
        //...
         console.log("works");
      }
  }
  catch(err) {

    //if error then re-run after 0.5 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {  this.someFunction(); }, 500);
     console.log(err);

  }

}

//run func for the first time
this.someFunction();
```

Comment: its working as expected but this will be a infinite loop if this.myprovider.SomeVarIsNotUndefined is not defined it will keep calling itself every 500msec

Comment: There's likely a better way to approach this, but with that said, why aren't you checking `if(this.myprovider.SomeVarIsNotUndefined === undefined)` instead of trying to prompt an exception?

Comment: Even I tried your code it is working perfectly as you expected

Comment: Your code works as expected. If you could post the actual code which has a problem that will help.

Comment: I found that because I was using if myarray.length it was not working but it was with a string/number so I simply added a variable at the end of the function to complete the promise

Answer (score 1):

Below code works perfectly fine, for the first time the variable is undefined and the program flow goes to the catch block. Then in the catch block, I defined the variable and then set timeout function re-triggers the function and gives out console.log - "works"

```
<script>

function someFunction(){
  try {

      if(SomeVarIsNotUndefined){
        //...
         console.log("works");
      }
  }
  catch(err) {

    //if error then re-run after 0.5 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {  SomeVarIsNotUndefined = 1; this.someFunction(); }, 500);
     console.log(err);

  }

}

//run func for the first time
this.someFunction();
</script>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FP6TDP0ESYVW

Comment: I found that because I was using if myarray.length it was not working but it was with a string/number so I simply added a variable at the end of the function to complete the promise